# grub is not showing after installing of ubuntu 13.04 on windows8

Tags: boot, 13.04, dual-boot, system-installation

i'm using Windows 8.now i want the dual boot in my laptop with Ubunutu 13.04. i already installed ubuntu 13.04.But after installing Ubuntu whenever i start the system it is going to windows 8.how do i get GRUB menu for selecting OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this thread
http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Basically, make a live USB or CD of ubuntu and install boot-repair, then apply recommended repair